# Problems RVIZ no fixed frame

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

i'm working on RVIZ but can't set a fixed frame. There is no selection option in the dropdown.

i get the error message: No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [base] does not exist.

roswtf command return this error:

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:

- /rviz_1501573816403560019->/rosout (/rosout)
- /base_to_world->/rviz_1501573816403560019 (/tf_static)
- /robot_ref_publisher->/rviz_1501573816403560019 (/tf)
- /ref_base_to_world->/rviz_1501573816403560019 (/tf_static)
- /robot_state_publisher->/rviz_1501573816403560019 (/tf)

Please see if you can help. Thanks!

screenshot warning rviz: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz1aKuHf7HqgRlZaQWRTSkNFWjg

screenshot rviz: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz1aKuHf7Hqgdl9NTWpmWEtmdUU

tf tree: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz1aKuHf7HqgeXdkekxneHVNMjg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267813/problems-rviz-no-fixed-frame/) by [sawsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31405/sawsi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-01**:
What dropdown are you referring to? We'll need more information (such as screen shots, tf tree, etc.) to go off of.

**Comment by [sawsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31405/sawsi/) on 2017-08-02**:
I refer to dropdown fixed frame for set the global options. I have add screen shots of rviz and tf tree. (build with command rgt_tf_tree).
i hope someone can help me!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-02**:
It would be helpful for the site (and its users!) if you copy and paste the terminal output (first screenshot) here and used the formatting button to make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error from `roswtf` isn't always a problem. I believe that it could be just that it's taking longer than the timeout limit of `roswtf` to connect.

As for the fixed frame issue in `rviz`, you're looking in the wrong dropdown to set the fixed frame. Go to `Global options` then set the `Fixed Frame` option from there.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sawsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31405/sawsi/) on 2017-08-07**:
Many thanks for your response!
I can't set a Fixed Frame at global options because the dropdown is empty.
Is the tf tree correct?
Do i need to connect Rviz / tf ?

**Comment by [sawsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31405/sawsi/) on 2017-08-17**:
It was a network configuration error!

**Comment by [lolito](https://answers.ros.org/users/35164/lolito/) on 2019-09-12**:
Hi i have the same problem, i don't have the drop-down list of fixed frame.
Can you tell me how do you fix it?
Thanks

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-09-12**:
@lolito You should create a new question for that